# Find the minimum and maximum of $h(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+|x|}+\dfrac{1}{1+|x-a_1|}$

Tags: calculus

> Let $a_1 \in \mathbb{R}$. Find the minimum and maximum of $h(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+|x|}+\dfrac{1}{1+|x-a_1|}$.

This question seems hard to solve since we don't know what $a_1$ is. We want both $|x|,|x-a_1|$ to be as small as possible or as large as possible to find the maximum or minimum, so how do I find where that is possible? Maybe it might occur at the median or some other point.

Comment: What would you normally do to find the minima and maxima of a function $f(x)$?

Comment: Can you see there is no minimum? By taking $x$ very large, we can make our expression as close to $0$ as we wish, but we cannot make it $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah, right, but what about the maximum?

Answer (score 3):

Set $b=a_1/2$ and the translation $x\mapsto x-b$, $y\mapsto y$. This leads to considering the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x-b|}+\frac{1}{1+|x+b|}
$$
and it's not restrictive to assume $b\ge0$. Leave out the case $b=0$, for the moment. The function is even, so we just need to study it for $x\ge0$ and we can write it as
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{1+b-x}+\dfrac{1}{1+x+b} & \text{if $0\le x<b$}\\[6px]
\dfrac{1}{1+x-b}+\dfrac{1}{1+x+b} & \text{if $x\ge b$}
\end{cases}
$$
You can see that $f(0)=2/(1+b)$ and that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0
$$
Thus there is no absolute minimum, because $f(x)>0$ for all $x$. We also have
$$
f(b)=1+\frac{1}{1+2b}
$$

The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{(1+b-x)^2}-\dfrac{1}{(1+b+x)^2} & \text{if $0\le x<b$}\\[6px]
-\dfrac{1}{(1-b+x)^2}-\dfrac{1}{(1+b+x)^2} & \text{if $x>b$}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $f$ is decreasing in the interval $(b,\infty)$ (and not differentiable at $b$). In the interval $[0,b)$ we can write
$$
f'(x)=\frac{4x(1+b)}{(1+b-x)^2(1+b+x)^2}
$$
so the function has zero derivative at $0$ and is increasing in the interval $(0,b)$.

This should be enough to finish up.

The case $b=0$ is quite easy:
$$
\frac{2}{1+|x|}\le 2
$$
for all $x$, equality only for $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously $h(x) > 0$, with $h(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.  Thus the infimum is $0$, but there is no minimum.

Candidates for the maximum are the two points ($0$ and $a_1$) where the function is non-differentiable, plus any points where the derivative is $0$.  However, the function is convex on intervals not containing $0$ and $a_1$, so points where the derivative is $0$ would be local minima, not maxima.

Comment: How do you know the function doesn't increase without bound?

Comment: "there is no minimum": are you sure ?

Comment: @user19405892: The function does not increase without bound because each term is $\le 1$.

Comment: I think this is easier said then done. How can we find all points where the function is not differentiable and where it has a local maxima?

Comment: @user19405892: The denominators are never zero, and are differentiable everywhere except where the absolute values are zero, so $h$ is differentiable everywhere except $x=0$ and $x=a_1$. These are your likely candidates (indeed, in light of Robert Israel's remarks, your only candidates) for the locations of the maxima. Also notice that $h(0) = h(a_1)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I'm sure.  There is a local minimum at $a_1/2$, but no global minimum.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, $a_1=2$.

The domain can be decomposed in three pieces:

$$x\le0\implies f(x)=\frac1{1-x}+\frac1{3-x},\\
0\le x\le2\implies f(x)=\frac1{1+x}+\frac1{3-x}=\frac4{(1+x)(3-x)},\\
2\le x\implies f(x)=\frac1{1+x}+\frac1{x-1}.$$

The first (magenta) and third (black) pieces have a derivative which is the sum of two squares and doesn't cancel. The second piece (light green) is the inverse of a downward parabola and has a local minimum at $(1,1)$.

The junction points form two maxima (angular points), at $(0,\frac43)$ and $(2,\frac43)$.

[image]

For other values of $a_1$, stretch the plot horizontally.

Comment: I don't want to assume without loss of generality.

Comment: @user19405892: then replace $2$ by $a_1$ wherever it belongs (also the "hidden" $2$). It makes very little difference.